# iTunes 11.1 won't let user delete podcast titles?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I got as far as [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86371/does-itunes-want-us-to-delete-podcasts-from-the-list/97095#97095) where my issue came up only as a comment.

[image]

I've heard and deleted the 9/6 and 9/13 episodes, but they appear in the list. 
A right-click (sorry yes I'm on a Mac but have a mouse with r-c) shows no delete option.

So, when looking at my list of podcasts, I'm potentially looking at hundreds of podcasts that aren't current, I have a few that are daily, and they now show 100+ of old episodes. Any podcast fans have this issue and way to fix this? 
Note, I checked the source folder for the podcast title, and this are not there, not taking HD space, just space on this list. Last - I know there's a n option to limit the number shown, but there are some shows that I'd want o keep more than this limit. If I am away from iTunes for a while, I still want the dailies available.

[image]

Note - it's all podcasts that have this issue, th image is to show one example, but they all have a long list of old shows.

10/4/13 update from the notes on 11.1.11 update :

> This update resolves an issue that may cause iTunes Extras to display
>   incorrectly, fixes a problem with deleted podcasts, and improves
>   stability.

And after updating, the issue is gone. Which, of course, renders this thread delete-worthy. Thank you for the comments and support!

Comment: If only we didn't have to rely upon McSweeny's to catalog the versions of iTunes that we should care about. - http://www.mcsweeneys.net/articles/my-favorite-versions-of-itunes

Comment: 11.1.1.11 seems to have fixed the problem, at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podcast listings are glorified RSS feeds with local cached content.

On iTunes 11.1, you can't hide or change the individual episodes that make up a podcast listing other an by deleting that entire feed from your list of podcasts. This simplifies the code, simplifies the states a podcast can be in, but aggravates anyone who used to like to curate their version of the RSS feed.

---

As to controlling the downloaded titles,  you can still hilight any episode and press the delete key to delete all selected episodes.

[image]

Your "continuous" indication is an odd marking and probably the result of a malformed stream from the podcast server or other odd state that the database file that tracks iTunes podcasts. You might need to delete any downloaded podcasts you wish to keep (rescuing them from the trash if you move them there) and then unsubscribe from that podcast.

Once the history of plays is clear, you might attempt to delete any remaining entries and then re-subscribe. At that point, you could adjust the auto delete settings for that podcast, refresh the episode list and manually re-import the shows you had saved above.

Comment: in iTunes 11.1 you cannot delete a podcast from the list view. The delete button simply does not work.

Comment: Hmm... I deleted three podcast episodes to test this answer before posting. It's how I captured the dialog and inspected the actual moving to the trash of my downloaded files. Perhaps the concept of list view is the clue - I browse the library and not a playlist.

Comment: I browsed through the library as well with iTunes 11.1 and I'm not able to delete the podcasts. All episodes in the rss feed show and there's no option to hide them either.

Comment: To be clear, podcasts on the directory can never be deleted. You can delete a local copy of an episode, but the publisher controls how many episodes are listed and you control how many download and stay local by regularly listening (to keep the new episodes downloading) and setting the auto delete settings globally or locally. The delete button can manually remove downloaded episodes only if they aren't already deleted by rule. iTunes has no hide function to suppress some of the possible downloads.

Comment: huh? in iTunes 11.0.5 you could delete a podcast so it didn't show up in the podcasts tab anymore, that functionality no longer works. It shows every available episode regardless of if it has been downloaded, listened to or anything else.

Comment: We are in total agreement - you can't suppress listings in 11.1 (which is the question at hand). You can use other software or change your expectations, but looking to get iTunes 11.1 to do something it doesn't anymore disregards the design change that was made. (Or were both missing some hidden, obscure or hiding in plain sight setting that someone else might need to point to our attention)

Comment: if this was an intentional design change then they're really moving in the wrong direction

Comment: I concur fully with @Matt. And it used to work before 11.1. And when I delete downloaded episodes, yes, they are removed from the hard disk, but they remain in the list with a small 'cloud-and-arrow' to indicate they are not downloaded. I vote to return to the previous behaviour!

Comment: I'm still reading here. I appreciate the comments, and at least I'm not missing something. The prior Rev did not do this. There are bigger things to worry about, but I'm with Matt, this is a bad change. News From Lake Wobegone goes back 3 years. Wow. bmike, thanks for answering, accepting it.

Comment: fyi for anyone else who reads this the bug is fixed in 11.1.1

Answer (score 5):

I can't add a simple comment as I don't have the rep, but I'd like to add something to this discussion:

1. In 11.1 you *can* delete downloaded podcasts just like always. The difference is that, while the file will disappear from your HD, the listing for that file will still be presented to you in itunes. The *listings* are not deletable (currently). This is causing confusion because, formerly, deleting the file would also automatically delete the listing. Note that I'm assuming that's why bmike was able to display the delete box above--he was deleting an existing file from his HD.
2. This has happened before. Apple just doesn't seem to test (or really understand--see the new 'podcast' app) podcast user behavior. Thus every once in a while itunes gets updated and you get a bug like this one.
3. This is a BUG not a purposeful change. There are podcasts that create a dozen files to download per day, normally I could just click the download all button and get them all at once. But because now I cannot remove old, already discarded podcasts from the list, the download all button will download... hundreds of files. It's not logical that this would be considered a feature. It's a bug, which they've had before, and they've fixed before.

It'll get fixed, but as I recall it took a month or so last time... sorry folks, and welcome to the Apple way!

Edit:

just to prove without a doubt that this is a bug, note that there is still a selection when you right click on a podcast 'show old episodes'. This setting *used* to re-query the rss feed and list out all the available podcasts so that you could download them. This was needed because, as discussed, when you deleted a local file, the listing for it also was removed. The way 11.1 works now is similar to if the 'show old episodes' button was perpetually set 'on', with no way to turn it off. Thus, either this behavior (not being able to delete podcast listings) is a bug, or the continued presence of the 'show old episodes' button is a bug.

One of them is a bug, I'm guessing it's this new behavior, not the presence of the seemingly-redundant 'show old episodes' button.

HTH! Have patience and it'll get fixed :)

Comment: Thanks. I see it's deleted from my drive, and the listing means 'available to download.' I have a long list of podcasts, and for some, it's just 3-5 that show. For those that have dozens, the view isn't great, I used to listen and delete, so my full list wasn't even a full two pages, now it's dozens. I hope they agree it's a bug to fix. My question got little response at first, and I thought no one quite cared about this issue. If no overwhelming objection, the fix may not be a priority.

Comment: Joe, you should submit feedback to apple using the 'Provide Itunes Feedback' selection on the help menu of itunes. That (afaik) is the only thing apple actually looks at. They are known for not looking at their own forums (which are filled with complaints about this very issues btw). It's definitely a bug, it'll get fixed, but submitting feedback to them can't hurt.